# Adding to a List does a Duplicate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to add to a List a Candidate description, and it creates a new candidate.
Here are my Model and Controller:

```
public class Candidate : BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string ProfileText { get; set; }
    public Byte[] CV { get; set; }
    public string CVNAME { get; set; }
    public List<Profile> ProfileList { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public Boolean Saving { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfDescription { get; set; }
    public List<Candidate> DescriptionList { get; set; }
    public Candidate()
    {
        DescriptionList = new List<Candidate>();
    }

}


public IActionResult CandidateHistory(int Id)
    {

        using (var applicationcontext = new ApplicationContext())
        {
            var candidate = applicationcontext.Candidates.AsNoTracking().Include(q => q.DescriptionList).Single(q => q.Id == Id); //Recieving all the data from the Candidate With the ID = Id
            if (candidate == null) //if Candidate isn't found return a error page
            {
                return NotFound();
            }


            return View(candidate);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost, ActionName("CandidateHistory")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult CandidateHistoryPost([Bind("Description, Title, DateOfDescription, Saving")]Candidate candidate ,int Id)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (var applicationContext = new ApplicationContext())
                {  var candidates = applicationContext.Candidates.AsNoTracking().Include(q => q.DescriptionList).Single(q => q.Id == Id);    //Getting all the DATA from the Candidate with the Id passed in the Get Method
                    candidates.DescriptionList.Add(candidates);
                    applicationContext.Candidates.Update(candidates);
                    applicationContext.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("CandidateHistory");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException ex)
        {
            //Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " + "Try again, and if the problem persists " + "see your system administrator.");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Maybe It's because I'm adding an Candidate Model insde a candidate model List?
As you can see in this image it does create a new Candidate for each description I add to the list.
[image]

Comment: step through with a debugger

Comment: Check my solution, it is just a typing mistake.

Comment: @AbhishekJaiswal it still duplicates in candiate

Comment: Update your problem without typo.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're retrieving the list using `AsNoTracking`. That literally means that EF is not tracking these items. Then, when you save the list back, it attaches them as new items.

Comment: Even If I remove it still creates a new Candidate

Comment: Please add a sample code that will work in this situation

Answer (score 0):

AsNoTracking tells Entity Framework not to cache the dataset. Basically, it goes back to the db for each call instead of using the internal memory. Seems like you have a circular reference with your list. Why don't you just return a list of Candidate objects instead of using a nested collection? Return IList from your database call.

Comment: I have removed the `AsNoTracking` and still does the same thing

Comment: Please add a sample code that will work in this situation

Comment: instead of:var candidate = applicationcontext.Candidates.AsNoTracking().Include(q => q.DescriptionList).Single(q => q.Id == Id); try var candidate = applicationconext.Candidates.Where(w => w.id == id).toList(); ---This will return a list of Candidate objects. I'm still confused on why you have a nested list of objects within the same class object so I may be completely on the wrong path here.

Answer (score 0):

This seems odd to me...

```
var candidates = applicationContext.Candidates.AsNoTracking().Include(q => q.DescriptionList).Single(q => q.Id == Id);    //Getting all the DATA from the Candidate with the Id passed in the Get Method
candidates.DescriptionList.Add(candidates);
```

I interpret this to mean you are adding the base Candidate entity to itself.  I cannot read the image so I cannot verify your results.  But you may wind up with some really **wierd** behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You had a typing mistake, I guess. Here =>

You are doing `candidates.DescriptionList.Add(candidates);`

You should be doing `candidates.DescriptionList.Add(candidate);`

Remove parameter passed to the method is `candidate`, and you are adding `candidates`.